# Strange line in legacy C code running on Linux

Tags: c, centos7

I am attempting to run some old legacy C code on CentOS 7 and it is causing problems.

The same line of code runs fine on CentOS 6.  But on CentOS 7 it stomps all over the value of some unrelated variables and objects.

There are two char pointers defined in the function:

```
 char *buf;
 char *cdat;
```

Then there hundreds of lines of code that go about pointing "buf" and "cdat" at actual data.

The line that actually causes the problem is this line:

```
 *buf++ = *cdat;
```

This code compiles fine and it runs.  But, when it runs on CentOS 7 it causes a bunch of unrelated variable to take on very weird values.

Does anyone know what this line is attempting to do and why it seems to run fine in CentOS 6 but not in CentOS 7?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ? Your code has [undefined behavior](https://riptutorial.com/c/topic/364/undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char *buf;
> char *cdat;
>
> *buf++ = *cdat;
> ```

Wait - is that *exactly* how it appears in the code?  If so, then the *problem* is that neither `buf` nor `cdat` are pointing anywhere meaningful, and the value of the random thing `cdat` is pointing to is copied to the random thing that `buf` is pointing to, and `buf` is advanced to point to the next random thing.

If, on the other hand, `cdat` and `buf` are assigned to point to actual objects and you've just left out that code, then again, the value of the thing that `cdat` points to is copied to the thing that `buf` points to, and `buf` is advanced to point to the next thing.

It's possible that whatever `buf` is supposed to be pointing to after that has changed between CentOS 6 and CentOS 7, but without more context I can't say for sure.

Comment: Yes, there are hundreds (or thousands) of lines that go about pointing buf and cdat to actual values in memory.  I just included those lines in order to show that they are pointers pointing to char data.  But the actual problem occurs when the "*buf++ = *cdat" line is executed.